# How to use Github in VS Code while also using an ftp

Tags: github, ftp

I have my website on my server, and I'm currently using FTP-simple in VS Code to work on it. However I want my code to be backed up using GitHub. I've made a repository and can open it in VS Code but I can't figure out how to combine the Github feature with FTP-simple as FTP-simple creates a temporary workspace???? Where have I gone wrong?

Maybe if I can get FTP-simple to create a local workspace that isn't temporary? Or is there another way to upload and download from my server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.